# anchor tag onclick is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnSaveComments" runat="server"
        onclick="EnterComments();" class="btn btn-sm btn-info no-radius">&nbsp;Send</a>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSaveComments").click(function(e) {
        EnterComments();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function EnterComments() {
    alert("test");
}
```

When I checked with debugger, it got inside `document.ready` but it didn't get inside the function `EnterComments`

Comment: put `e.preventDefault();` before `EnterComments`.

Comment: Its working for me http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/8nSSL/

Comment: it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/43fC3/

Comment: did you include jquery.min.js??

Comment: Please make sure your jquery library path

Comment: Also no need to write onclick="EnterComments(); attr on anchor tag, when you are defining it in ready() function.

Comment: working.. http://jsfiddle.net/dY4sJ/

Comment: i have tried calling the function before e.preventDefault, included jquery.min.js, removed onclick too.... but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see the code below :

HTML :

```
 <span class="input-group-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnSaveComments" runat="server"
                 onclick="EnterComments();" class="btn btn-sm btn-info no-radius"><i class="icon-share"></i>&nbsp;Send</a>
                </span>
```

JS :

```
function EnterComments() {
    console.log("test");
    alert("hi");
        }
```

Hope you find it useful.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/Vq0Yi5mu9y0RRK5tIhYt?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

`EnterComments()` is called twice here.

Remove `onclick="EnterComments();"` and try once.

It should work then

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<a href="#" id="anchor_tag" onclick="alert('You are clicked TEST TEXT');">TEST TEXT</a>
```

SCRIPT CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#anchor_tag').click(function() {
        alert('You have clicked test text'); 
    });


    enter code here

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: I gave it this way. When i click on the link iam navigated to the page where list of all the controls pages are given inside that folder. but still the function is not getting called.